# Setting up a server at home for Android app

Tags: ssh, dns

I'm currently developing a simple multiplayer game app for Android and I need to have a server to which the users connect to.I'd like to set up this server at home. I have a dynamic IP address,so someone told me I'd have to set up a local DNS server or something like that. I'm not even sure where to start with setting up a DNS server, everything I found was for windows 2003 and linux. Nothing for XP? If any one can shed some light on this matter, explain a bit how setting a DNS works or supply a link with "setting up local DNS for dummies" I'd be grateful.

Also, besides setting up a DNS so I can find the server every time, how about the communication with it? I'd like for it to be as secure as possible. Another friend told me something about communicating via SSH, which is again something I am not accustomed to.

So if someone could explain some of these concepts or offer some GOOD link for that that would be great. I'm very confused :)

Thanks

**EDIT**

Btw, the server is in Java and currently i'm communicating from Android emulator to the server (which is localhost) via sockets.

Comment: Something like http://www.no-ip.com/ wouldn't do the trick?

Comment: hmm...i think this is what i need yes ... still looking it over. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a simple thing you're trying to achive. First you have to create your own server on your machine (maybe you're done with this step), then you have to make this server available for everyone. At this point, I suggest the DynDNS service:

http://lifehacker.com/124804/geek-to-live--how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-your-home-web-server

A local DNS by default help **you** to find your own servers by name instead of IP address, but if you have a usual internet service with dynamic IP, you need an external DNS provider to route your clients to your server. (read the link above for the full explanation)
About the SSH security: Yes, you will need some security settings indeed, but that could be a very hard problem sometimes. You can set your server to work with SSL sockets, which is a part of the core J2SE release. It will work against some sort of attack, but none against others. Running your own server will raise unexpected numbers of problems, prepare for that.

Comment: And if i were to not use my own server, are there any hosting firms which would let me set up my java application on their servers? If so, i guess they are expensive, no? If there is another easier and securer way of doing it, please do tell :)

Comment: There are two cases:
1. hosting service: most of the companys specialized for webapplications, that's not perfect for you, but you can surely find a way to work on one of these
2. VPS service: you have a remotely accessible standalone computer (look-a-like, it runs on a virtualized environment in fact), you can do whatever you want on the machine, and you may get help from the administrators about firewalls, DDOS avoidance, etc.
You can buy both from about 10$, or something like that.

Comment: Excellent. Any suggestions for a good VPS service? If you know any or have used one. Thank you very much btw.

Comment: I know some, but unfortunately only in my own country. But I hope you can find something on Google.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comment to your post, something like http://www.no-ip.com or http://www.dnsdynamic.org would solve the issue with your dynamic ip - You do not need a local DNS server.

With regards to communication, i believe that SSH is linux/unix only. Since you wish to use Windows for the server, FTP or Remote Desktop would be best. Choose FTP if all you want to do is manage your files, choose remote desktop if you wish to manage your entire computer. I've had good results with the FileZilla FTP server on windows (http://filezilla-project.org/)

With that said, i think you would be better off buying a simple and cheap hosted service instead of using your own computer - you can get something that can run your java app for $5/month some places, and compared with the annoyance of having a local server running in your house, it might be worth it.

Comment: Hmm, i didn't know there existed such a service. And at 5$ a month it wouldn't be expensive at all. Do you know of any such services (link or names)? I'd be grateful. Or at least how should i search on Google? What are the common names for these type of services.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I would suggest that you search for "java web application hosting" in Google - However, start by checking out Google App Engine (http://code.google.com/appengine/), as i believe it will fit well with your needs for the android app. I don't have any personal expreince with App Engine, but I've heard some good things. As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, getting a VPS might be a good idea if your application does not fit within the Google App Engine setup - I have good experience with http://hetzner.de.